# Firedac Sqlite Query fails when query string contains "!"

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac

I'm trying to load records from another database into SQLite.  I'm using Delphi 10.4 (Firemonkey) and a FireDAC Query component. When I pass the following query string to the Query component:

```
INSERT INTO BrandName (BrandName, WebSite, Email) values ("Mount It!", "", "")
```

it fails with the following exception:

```
Project MigrateData.exe raised exception class ESQLiteNativeException with message '[FireDAC][Phys][SQLite] Error: 2 values for 3 columns'.
```

When I remove the "!" from the record in the file, it processes normally, and if I run this query in the SQLite DB Browser it executes normally as well.

I'm using sqlite3.dll version 3.36.  Here is the code I'm using, in case it helps:

```
  with MemDataMod.BrandTable do begin
    First;
    while not EOF do begin
      SQLStr := 'INSERT INTO BrandName (BrandName, WebSite, Email)'
            + ' values ("' + FieldByName('BrandName').AsString + '", "'
            + FieldByName('WebSite').AsString + '", "'
            + FieldByName('Email').AsString + '")';
      MySQLDB.BlankQuery.SQL.Clear;
      MySQLDB.BlankQuery.SQL.Append(SQLStr);
      MySQLDB.BlankQuery.ExecSQL;
      Next;
    end;
  end;
```

I can't imagine why the "!" would make a difference, but it seems to. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `!` (exclamation mark) character, and several others, require special handling in FireDAC SQL, because they have special meanings in it.

This is fully documented in the ["Special Character Processing"](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)#Special_Character_Processing) section of the [Preprocessing Command Text (FireDAC)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)) documentation, see the ResourceOptions `MacroCreate`, `MacroExpand`, `EscapeExpand` properties in that section.

BTW, it's a bad idea to construct SQL by concatenating text which includes user input, or field values derived from it, because it is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't realized the special handling was a FireDAC issue.  I'm not worried about SQL Injection Attacks in this particular instance.  The program is a data conversion utility for a PC based product I sell - converting from one database to another.  It is all the user's data so there would be no incentive to doctor your own data to break the conversion.